# How to combine \overbrace and \overline the way I want?

Tags: math-mode

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$u=\overline{\exists degree\hspace{3pt} \overbrace{\big(\underbrace{degrees(course, degree)}_{u_1}\wedge\underbrace{degree\neq 1}_{u_2}\big)}^{u_3}}$

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

I want that the `\overbrace` with the `u_3` label will appear **above** the `\overline`, but still encompass only the parentheses. I can't find a way to do it.

Can it be done somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typeset the whole thing three times. The first one as a horizontal phantom to set the width, the second time as the real thing, the third time as a vertical phantom.

The first two times the two objects are superimposed with `\ooalign`.

In order to save typing, the object is saved in a temporary command, which takes as argument an invisible rule stating its height.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for giving context

\newcommand{\func}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\[
\newcommand{\contents}[1]{%
  \exists\, \var{degree} \: 
  \overbrace{
    #1
    \bigl(\,
      \underbrace{\func{degrees}(\var{course},\var{degree})}_{u_1}
      \wedge
      \underbrace{\var{degree}\neq 1}_{u_2}
    \,\bigr)
  }^{u_3}
}
u={\ooalign{%
    $\displaystyle\overline{\rule{0pt}{2ex}\hphantom{\contents{}}}$\cr
    $\displaystyle\contents{\rule{0pt}{2.75ex}}$\cr
}}
\vphantom{\contents{\rule{0pt}{2.75ex}}}
\]
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you define the command inside `document` body? Is there some reason? Nice solution, by the way.

Comment: @Sigur It's probably something that won't be used anywhere else, so defining it in the math display is just like typing it “there”. If it was in the preamble it would be more difficult to access in case some correction has to be made.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution prints the formula only once (no three times):

```
$$
  u =
  \vbox{\def\shiftA{3.3ex}\def\shiftB{\vrule height2.7ex width0pt} %spec. numbers for this formula
    \kern\shiftA\hrule\kern-\shiftA
    \hbox{$\displaystyle
       \exists\, {\it degree} 
           \overbrace{\big(
               \underbrace{\shiftB{\rm degrees}({\it course},{\it degree})}_{u_1}
               \wedge
               \underbrace{{\it degree}\neq 1}_{u_2}
           \big)}^{u_3}
    $}}
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\def\contento{\exists\,\mathit{degree}}
\def\contenti{\big(
    \underbrace{{\rm degrees}({\it course},{\it degree})}_{u_1}
    \wedge
    \underbrace{{\it degree}\neq 1}_{u_2}
    \big)}
\[
u=\overline{\contento\phantom{\contenti}}
  \llap{$\displaystyle
        \overbrace{\vphantom{\overline{\contento\contenti}}\contenti}^{u_3}
    $}
\]

\[
u=\overline{\contento\vphantom{\contenti}}\!
\overbrace{
    \overline{\vphantom{\contento}\contenti}
}^{u_3}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want that the `\overbrace` with the `u_3` label will appear **above** the `\overline`, but still encompass only the parentheses. I can't find a way to do it.

So. Forget `\overline`. Simply use `\hspace` and draw a `\rule` at the desired position, height, length, (and width.)

```
$$
u=\exists degree\hspace{3pt}
\overbrace{\big(\underbrace{degrees(course, degree)}_{u_1}
\wedge\underbrace{degree\neq 1}_{u_2}\big)
   \hspace{-21em}\rule[2.25ex]{21em}{}
}^{u_3}
$$
```

[image]

Comment: It is better IMHO to write all the text in textmode. You can give a little space between \exist and degree. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Sure, I agree in principle with writing text in textmode `\textrm` etc., but that wasn't the question. That's a different issue entirely.

Comment: Yes, my it was only a suggestion like never to use double $$. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: I was using KaTex in wiki.js.